# What Happens if i kill php process while magento site is running

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, orders

I want to know that what happens if i **kill** php process from my godaddy hosting account while somebody is placing an order on my website. does that effect my site anyway?.

after killing php process my site works more faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "killing". Killing a process can be executed in many ways.

If you mean stop and restart php nothing is gonna happen, your website will not have any side effect. If you mean something like `kill -KILL` i woul dnot suggest you to do it because sometimes you may have random side effects (it is a very remote scenarion, but can happen).

About the increased website speed after a PHP restart is a quite common effect. If you have php-fpm i would suggest you to tune `pm.max_requests` parameter.

If you have speed problems i would suggest you to **tune parameters**, increase resources or **optimize your website** instead of restarting php processes.

Hope it helps.